# Error when replace whole page using JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, replace

I have a php variable with content is html:

[image]

When I using Javascript:

```
document.body.innerHTML.replace("<?php echo $content ?>");
```

to replace whole page, it say error:

[image]

and jQuery is same error:

```
jQuery('html').html("<?php echo $content ?>");
```

[image]

There any way I can do that, JS and PHP solution are ok.

Comment: Read the generated source.  Your string is invalid; you need to escape it.

Comment: The `<?php echo $content ?>` might be adding some unwanted characters

Comment: Also, `replace()` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: @mickmackusa still same error.

Comment: @mickmackusa not so fast, there's no actual way to know it doesn't return an unescaped back slash too

Comment: @mickmackusa still same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be less about quotes and special characters and more about newlines. 
 You can use json to protect against all these character occurrences.

```
document.body.innerHTML = <?=json_encode($html)?>;
```

This works on my server:

```
<?php
$html = <<<HTML
<span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </span>
<a href="http://google.com">Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.</a>
<strong>When an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book</strong>
HTML;
?>

<html>
    <body>blah</body>
    <script>
        document.body.innerHTML = <?=json_encode($html)?>;
    </script>
</html>
```

---

Of course, you can just use `document.body.innerHTML = <?=$html?>;` if you declare `$html = json_encode($html);` earlier in your script.

Comment: Thank so much, but the $content get from file_get_contents, so I can not make "<<<HTML" string as your example.

Comment: That's okay, it doesn't matter for your task.  That is merely how I set up my demo so that I didn't have to escape any quotes.  Please accept my answer if it works for you.

Comment: Ok it worked with <?=json_encode($html)?> without "<<<HTML". Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Convert to HTML Special Characters then convert back with JS?

```
var str = "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($content); ?>";
str = str.replace('&gt;', '>').replace('&lt;', '<').replace('&quot;', '"');
jQuery('body').html(str);
```

Comment: It still say SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

Comment: @HữuCôngHoàng That probably means the HTML is incorrectly parsed (i.e. `<html`)