# I receive an error, but I do not know what it is

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I must form a single row table with elements of the mysql server chosen by the ID, the table runs perfectly (it is displayed in the html file).
I execute it in javascript file through an ajax function, when I call the function , my javascript collapses, please help me

```
 <?php
    $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db_dinagri");

    $salida = "";
    $query = "SELECT * FROM productos ORDER By ID";
    $cantidad = 0;

    //$Unidad = $fila['ProductU'];

    if(isset($_POST['e']) && isset($_POST['c'])){
        $q = $conexion->real_escape_string($_POST['e']);
        $query = "SELECT ID, ProductN, ProductP, ProductU, ProductS FROM productos 
                  WHERE ID LIKE '%".$q."%'";
        $cantidad = $_POST['c'];
    }

    $resultado = $conexion->query($query);
    $salida.="<table class='table table-sm' id='tabla' autofocus>
                    <thead class='thead-light'>
                        <tr>
                               <th scope='col'>Cantidad</th>
                            <th scope='col'>Unid.</th>
                            <th  scope='col'>ARTICULO</th>
                            <th  scope='col'>P. Unitario</th>
                            <th>TOTAL</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>";
    $fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc();
                  $salida.="<tr>
                        <td>".$cantidad."</td>
                        <td>".$fila['ProductU']."</td>
                        <td>".$fila['ProductN']."</td>
                        <td>".$fila['ProductP']."</td>
                        <td>40</td>
                     </tr>";
    //if($resultado->num_rows > 0){
      //  $i
        //for($i=1; $i<4; $i++){
        //  echo "hola";
        //}
        //while($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){


        //}

        $salida.="</tbody</table>";


     echo $salida;
    $conexion->close();

    ?>
```

Comment: Open developers console. Explain "collapses".

Comment: It just shows me that the problem is when the ajax function is called and it does not show any php problem, but the javascript collapses, it eliminates ajax function and it worked perfectly, the problem is the php, and the console does not give me errors of the php

Comment: I dont see any javascript

Comment: `function order(e, c){
  $.ajax({
      url: 'order.php',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'html',
      data: {e: e, c: c},
  })
  .done(function(r){
      $('#order').html(r);
  })
  .fail(function(){
    console.log("error");
  })
} order(1, 5);`

Comment: What do you mean by **javascript collapses** ?

Comment: When I call order(), all other functions of my js file stop working, when they are called they do not respond ** THE JAVASCRIPTS COLLAPSE **

Comment: what is the reason to write .fail(function(){  }

Comment: You can start by fixing ` $salida.="</tbody</table>";`.

Comment: So that it shows if there is an error, but it does not show me anything in the console

Comment: Roamer i dont understand ??can you explain me

Comment: `$salida.="</tbody></table>";`

Comment: Is this the issue? https://stackoverflow.com/a/49165225/2943403

Answer (score -1):

Whenever you make an ajax call to your server you wont get any message for any php error as it become internal issue and in your console log it will show internal error . Better do a step by step with small checkings like first check whether the data you are passing is going there or not, where your query is correct or nor etc.
In your case the query is correct it seems , your ajax call is correct to I guess there might be error in fetching from the query check that and also no need to use '.'in the php var that is
 ".$cantidad."
Change it to
 "$cantidad"
And if the error still exist then try doing all the result where your table is forming with html code in a while loop cause your query might be fetching more that one rows and change the "dataType" in the ajax call to "text".

Comment: The order file makes the table in index.php file, when that happens the file js stops.That is, the data is passed correctly to the order.php file but when it returns the response through the file js (it arrives at the index.php) and the file js stops

Comment: So you are trying to say that you are getting the response from the ajax call but problem is in the html file?kingly elobrate the error .what you asked in the question implies that there is a problem in the php code....your ajax seems correct only

Comment: I think the problem could be in mysql but not exactly where, Because I receive the answer ajax.

Comment: Replace Your real_escape_string with mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['e']);

Comment: but js file it's still collapse

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\login\order.php on line 28

Comment: remove ',' after the data:{e:e,c:c }

Comment: I think the problem could be fetch_assoc();, what I do?

Comment: use mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);

Comment: $fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);

Comment: Remove the ajax call use the postman chrome extension and send the data in the post method to data link and see  for the error